# Adding Flash Player Slide Show On Website

Tags: flash, show, slide, product

I have an iPhone cases website where i want to add products slide show on each page.  I am not expert on coding. So i would highly appreciate if anyone suggest some good product or resource for making a products slideshow that can be added on all pages.

Homepage - http://www.iphone5casesbuy.com/

There are just few iPhone cases right now but i am planning to add 20 to 30 to more. There is a slideshow option in the theme but i do not like that also it does not appear on all pages.

What are the best possible solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Using Flash for a site targeted to iPhones is a terribe idea, iPhone doesn't even support flash! Which is one of the reasons i hate Apple btw.

Comment: The (good) reason Apple decided not to allow Flash is because Flash Player sucks juice out of a portable computer like a baby sucks a tit. And I should know, I've been writing Flash Player applications in two and a half different languages since 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flash for and iPhone cases is indeed a bad idea, you are alienating your target market. One of the best sliders out there is the Nivo slider http://nivo.dev7studios.com/. It can display a whole bunch of images in a really cool way, is super easy to use and it can be viewed on damn near every device.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, basically i just want to attract attention of the customers by providing the slide show and  i was not aware from that iPhone does not support flash.

Answer (score 0):

For slideshow display on mobile devices, I always use the [Web Album Maker](http://web-album-maker.com/), which take use of Javascript and CSS. However do not be confused, it is very easy to use, users do not need to have any coding knowledge.